# Why does Select-All in Face-Select mode also select isolated edges?

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

Blender v2.79.

Let's say I have to extrude all faces of this planar construction containing two edges not included in faces, and one isolated vertex:

[image]

In this object, there are not hidden vertices, edges or faces:

[image]

If I select all faces in Face-Select mode, the result (after extrusion of the selection) is this one:

[image]

The orphan edges have been selected, which isn't what I expected since it is not possible to select the edges manually (e.g. by using Border-Select) in this mode. Looks like a bug to me.

But if I select all edges in Edge-Select mode, then switch to Face-Select mode, the result is this one:

[image]

The edges are not kept selected. This behavior seems compliant to the documentation about [Select modes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#switching-select-mode):

> When switching modes in an “ascendant” way [...] the selected parts
>   will still be selected **if they form a complete element** in the new
>   mode.

Another strange result: Select All in Vertex-Select mode, switch to Face-Select and back to Vertex-Select:

[image]

Only one edge is kept selected as well as the isolated vertex. Seems completely buggy.

Anybody with a clear view of this? What is the correct way to select all complete faces for the extrusion?

Comment: There is probably a zero sized face there with overlapping vertex. Try removing doubles

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: I've updated the question, adding the number of faces reported by Blender. Nothing is hidden or co-located (the object is a plane where some faces and edges have been removed).

Comment: Do you have a file to take a look at? As it stands, I would say select one element, no matter whether it is a Vert, Edge or Face and Select Linked by pressing L with your mouse over your target or Ctrl + L if you are elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the isolated vertex still gets selected when you come back in Vertex select mode but there may be a good reason for it since that behavior is kept on the new versions of Blender.

But there is a way to select all the faces without selecting isolated edges or vertices and it's `Select Faces by Sides` (`Faces by sides` in newer versions) :

[image]

It will select all the 4 sided faces by default but you have options for it after you click :

[image]

You can change the number of vertices to 3 and change the type to `Greater than` if you want to select all the faces including n-gons. This will only select faces with 4 vertices and more. If you want to also select triangles, you redo that process once with options set to `Greater than` `3` and redo it again with `Equal to` `3`.

If you do this in face select mode, you will have all the faces but not isolated edges and vertices.